# Crear Array en javascript leyendo desde fichero local

Tags: javascript, array

necesito crear un Array en javascript del estilo var datos = [1,2,3,4]; para representar esos datos en un canvas. Los datos se recogerían de un fichero del escritorio con un input del tipo file.

El contenido del fichero sería:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Tengo este código en el que leo el contenido del archivo, pero no se parsearlo al array datos.

```js
 
 var datos = [1,1,10,1,1,1,1,1];
 
 function processFiles(files) {
     
 var file = files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 
 reader.onload = function (e) {
 var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"); 
 output.textContent = e.target.result;
 };
 
 reader.readAsText(file);
 
 var ctx = document.getElementById("grafico").getContext("2d");
 
 var lineChartData = {
 labels: ["0ms", "50ms", "100ms", "150ms", "200ms", "250ms", "300ms", "350ms"],
 datasets: [
   {
   label: ' miliVoltios',
   fillColor: "rgba(20,20,220,0.2)",
   strokeColor: 'rgba(200,2,2,1)',
   pointColor: "#1e45d7",
   pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
   pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
   pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   data: datos,
   borderWidth: 4
   },
  ]
 }
 var options = {
  scales: {
   yAxes: [{
     ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
     }
    }],
  }
 };

 window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {responsive: true}, {options: options});

 }
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
 <div id="fileOutput"></div>
```

Comment: Haz avances, y luego coméntanos lo que estas haciendo y como pretendes hacerlo. Por que es probable que te cierren la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @JoséMiguelSepulveda , es la primera vez que pregunto por aquí. He actualizado la pregunta con el código con el que estoy trasteando. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenias.

Al `e.target.result` podías hacer `split()` indicando el separador y ya te lo hace `array`

```js
var datos = [1,1,10,1,1,1,1,1];
 
 function processFiles(files) {
     
 var file = files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 
 reader.onload = function (e) {
 var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"); 
 output.textContent = e.target.result;
  
  var array = e.target.result.split("\r\n");
  console.log(array);
 };
 
 reader.readAsText(file);
 
 

 
 }
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
 <div id="fileOutput"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto! Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Alex me alegro. Un saludo